# Nvidia Quadro M2000 display issues

Tags: graphics-card, hdmi, nvidia-graphics-card, displayport, dell-optiplex

I recently picked up a NVidia Quadro M2000 online and have been anxiously waiting for my Display Port to HDMI dongle all week. I plug the card in along with the dongle and HDMI cord, but when I fire everything up, there's no signal. After removing the card and connecting the DP to my motherboard port, I receive signal.
Is there something I'm missing, is there something wrong with my setup, or should I just label the card as trash?
My set up:
Dell Optiplex 7010 (the big boy)
32gb RAM
750+ GB Storage
Original 275w power supply

Comment: That card alone needs 75W so, probably, the power supply isn't enough for starters.

Comment: Tried that with my 600w psu and the result was the same. Both times, after I turn it on and off, the system shuts down faster than when the thing is booted up and running, as if there's a system halt. Still can't see anything though. Any other ideas?